# QML TableView Mouse area does not propagate click to selection model

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TableView` with a delegate which contains a `MouseArea`. I would like to propagate a click to the `TableView` so that selection of items still works. However, with my `MouseArea` present I cannot select elements in `TableView`. How can I change this?

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    model: testModel
    selectionMode: SelectionMode.SingleSelection

    Component {
        id: testDelegate
        Item {
            id: delegateItem
                Text{
                    id: ctext
                    text: styleData.value
                    color: styleData.textColor
                }
                MouseArea {
                     id: mouseArea
                     acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
                     anchors.fill: parent
                     propagateComposedEvents: true
                      onClicked: {
                        console.log("click");
                        mouse.accepted = false
                      }

                 }


            }


    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "TestRole"
        delegate: testDelegate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the `onPressed` event instead of `onClicked` for the user interaction, propagating the event will also allow the selection in the `TableView` (including `ExtendedSelection` mode if needed):

```
MouseArea {
    // ...
    onPressed: {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick! Tried to combine it with onClicked, but the latter is not called then, sadly

Answer (score 0):

Since you redefined item delegate you should also implement item selection.
I usually do as below:

```
onClicked: {
    tableView.selection.clear();
    tableView.selection.select(styleData.row);
}
```